# Bootstrap Data Table on Click body

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I got this code perfectly working fine. If I use this code `if ($(e.target).is("#checkId_ i"))` and `if ($(e.target).is("[id^=checkId_] i"))` it is skipping the `if` statement in the body click. I just see this whole code from my friend but I ask him and he also don't know what is the reason.

What is the reason why code below is working and my test code is not?.

**Data Table**

```
columns:
    [
      { data: "testID", title: "Test Click Button", searchable: false, orderable: false, sClass: "alignCenter",
            "mRender": function (data) {
             return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs action" id="checkId_' + data + '"><i class="fa fa-dollar fa-fw action"></i></button>'
            + '&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs action" id="checkId2_' + data + '"><i class="fa fa-dollar fa-fw action"></i></button>';
            }
        }
    ]
```

**Body OnClick**

```
$('#tbltest tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    debugger;
    if ($(e.target).is("[id^=checkId_],[id^=checkId_] i")) {
        alert("Button 1 is Click");
    } else if ($(e.target).is("[id^=checkId2_],[id^=checkId2_] i")) {
        alert("Button 2 is Click");
    }
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use closest:

```
$('#tbltest tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(e.target).closest("[id^=checkId_]").length) {
        alert("Button 1 is Click");
    } else if ($(e.target).closest("[id^=checkId2_]").length) {
        alert("Button 2 is Click");
    }
});
```

Comment: I try your code and working fine. And I try to change the id like this `(#checkId2_)` and not working. Any reason why?

Comment: do you have any button with the id of `#checkId2_` ?

Comment: `#` refers to `ID` right?. Typo above. ("#checkId2_")

Comment: i don't understand what problem do you have the above code should work using the $("#checkId2_") selector will not work because you don't have a div with the id of checkId2_ you have a id that starts with checkId2_  , the selector i used in the closest function will select element that start with that string